# How to insert a div as the first element in a container with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have created a div with Javascript, this displays correctly, however it is not in the place where I want, I would like to put it inside a container as the first element. I'm not very good, I'm trying to learn, so sorry for the triviality of the question.

How do I put the div I created inside an already existing container as the first element?

Beyond that I would like to understand the logic of the operation, for example, how can I move the new div as the last element? Or as a second element ?

**This is the Js code**

```
// Add New Element
var newEl = document.createElement("div");
var text = document.createTextNode("Hello");
   newEl.appendChild(text);
   var element = document.getElementById("main_container");
   element.appendChild(newEl);
```

**This is what I am trying to achieve**

```
<div id="main_container" class="something">
   <div class="new_element">Hello</div>
   <div class="item">One</div>
   <div class="item">Two</div>
   <div class="item">Three</div>
</div>
```

**This is what I got for now**

```
<div id="main_container" class="something">
   <div class="item">One</div>
   <div class="item">Two</div>
   <div class="item">Three</div>
</div>
<div>Hello</div>
```

Comment: Look into [Node.insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const parent;
const newFirstChild;
parent.insertBefore(newFirstChild, parent.firstChild);
```

In your case:

```
element.insertBefore(newEl, element.firstChild)
```

If you want to insert at a different index you can do it like this:

```
parent.insertBefore(newEl, parent.children[2])
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/cowall/pen/wvmEVvw)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. So I solved the problem. However, it's not working for `parent.insertBefore(newEl, parent.children[2])` maybe I'm doing something wrong ...

Comment: Please see this [codepen](https://codepen.io/cowall/pen/wvmEVvw)

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```js
element.insertBefore(newEl, element.firstChild)
```